# How Can I Create A Custom Property Type

Tags: vb.net, types, properties

I don't really know how to explain this correctly, so I will try to be as simple as possible.

When you create a Boolean variable (for example) you get a little popup menu allowing you to chose either True or False.

Is there a way of creating a custom property that when referenced, gives a custom list of selectable options?

For example, I want to create a new property called Car_Model that gave users a selectable list of car makes (e.g. Holden, Ford, Chevy, Etc.) So using the property would be something like:

```
Dim _car as Car = New Car
Car.Car_Model = {Popup a list of selectable options here, e.g. Model.Holden, Model.Ford, Model.Chevy, etc.}
Car.Name = "Betsy"
...
```

So far I've only really worked with property types within a class, but I guess it's somehow related to creating my own 'Type'. So instead of String or Boolean it would be a Car_Model.

Hope that makes sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an Enumeration. You define it like this:

```
Public Enum CarModel
   BMW = 1
   Porsche = 2
   Audi = 3
   Ferrari = 4
End Enum
```

You can then define a variable of this type

```
Dim Model As CarModel = CarModel.Porsche
```

The enumeration can be understood as named integer variables. So you basically can also assign the respective number to the variable. Assigning values to the enumeration elements is not strictly needed and further properties can be defined using attributes. See MSDN for further details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx

Comment: Do I define the Enum within the Class with the properties (e.g. Car) or outside of that?

Comment: HeyJens, Good answer.+1

Comment: I create my enums as its own class. Just rename class as enum, like shown above. the enum can be within your model, but I don't do it that way.

Comment: Define it inside a class. It does not really matter in which class you define the enum. You may need to add a reference to the class where it is defined though.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Enum

```
  Public Enum Car_Model
        none = 0
        Mazda
        Chevy
        Ford
    End Enum
```